# Android MapView gets stackoverflow, without throwing an Exception

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I've added a MapView dynamically, and I'm doing something wrong.

While adding the MapView in the layout XML, everything works just fine, but when I add it dynamically the MapView seem to capture the UI thread in a stackoverflow, which never throws an Exception, and the application is no longer debuggable. The stack centers mainly on the Tile object, where it goes back and forth over the getTile(...) method, and a few others.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Adam.

Comment: This is some weird Ju-Ju... I've debugged the application step by step, and halted for about 2 min over before adding the view dynamically, and then it just worked, and now it is always working... WTH is going on, I've been at it for 5 hours now?

Comment: Could it be that my original key was revoked? the only reasonable explanation would be that the new debug key, I've introduced became valid just about now?

Comment: Can you paste something that shows us how you're "adding it dynamically?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but the api-keys for debug and release I had were out of date... once I've set new keys, it worked like a charm again...